# Ajax call to fetch data

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django-views

I'm making ajax call to fetch data from the function written in view file 
Code from view file :

```
def adminRenderConceptGraph(request,group_id,node_id=None):
  if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
    group_name = u'home'
    if node_id:
    req_node = node_collection.one({'_id':ObjectId(node_id)})
    template = 'ndf/graph_concept.html'
    variable = RequestContext(request, {'node':req_node })
    return render_to_response(template,variable)
```

its corresponding url is:`url(r'^graph/(?P<node_id>[^/]+)$', 'adminRenderConceptGraph', name='adminRenderConceptGraph'),`

the ajax call is made in jquery :

```
  selected_val = "/home/ajax/graph/" + atr
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: selected_val,
        dataType: "json",
        data:{
          group_id = '{{groupid}}',
          node_id = atr ,
        }
      })
```

I'm getting this error :

```
GSystem:3450 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Its pointing to last line. Where is the error ??
there is no error as such that I have found each time I remove the line having error the next one starts having syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object properties should be listed through `colon` sign and there should not be comma after the last property. Try this one:

```
var selected_val = "/home/ajax/graph/" + atr;
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: selected_val,
        dataType: "json",
        data:{
          group_id:'{{groupid}}',
          node_id: atr
        }
      })
```